# Extend Display Modes Hotkey

Tags: shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors, display, default

This is my first post to this forum, so please excuse missing details. If you should need any just ask and maybe tell me the terminal command as I just switched to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS a week ago.

But now to my problem:
I've got Ubuntu 18.04 installed on my Lenovo ThinkPad E470. My 'F7'-key is toggled to choose between extended display options. It shows four possible modes:

- only Laptop display
- extend to left
- mirror
- only external monitor

If I press my 'F7'-key it rotates through those modes and let's me choose any. But for my usage those four options are not enough. I want to add two more options to exactly this cycle:

- extend to right
- extend to top

So that in the end I can press the 'F7'-key and have the choice between six possibilities. I would also be willing to give up any of the default options in case I can only add four.

I don't know what information is necessary to solve this issue so I'm just gonna provide some:

- UEFI Bios Version: RODET94W (1.94)
- ME Firmware Version: 11.8.50.3399
- Machine Type Model: 20H1007XGE
- Graphics card: Intel HD Graphics 620 (integrated card)
- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- Gnome 3.28.2

Comment: i see its now super+p on 20.04

Answer (score 1):

That's some significant development work to make that happen. Not a switch to be flipped, but a fully designed and developed feature.

You may not be aware though that just visiting the display section in system settings enables you to rearrange your displays in any manner you like. It's not a single button press but it's pretty quick and easy to do, and the setting is retained for the next time that external display is attached.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't aware of that. Can you maybe tell me where to "find" this feature? I'd be willing to take some risks.

I am aware of the possibilities in my settings but it always feels like a bit of a work around since I often have to disable my internal display.